What is the correct way to get the ataProgram in the mainnet-beta cluster?
I kept getting this error "ProgramNotRecognizedError: The provided program name [splAssociatedToken] is not recognized in the [mainnet-beta] cluster.
please what is the correct program name to use in this context to get the programId for my spl  token?

What are you trying to do? Can you share more info on what exactly is throwing this error?
